# How to send message to Slack channel after triggering global shortcut

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

When we trigger Global shortcut, Slack makes a call to the app but there is no `channel` or `response_url` fields in request payload.
`GlobalShortcutContext` has only `triggerId` field unlike `MessageShortcutContext` that also has `channelId` and `responseUrl`.

How are we supposed to send messages to the channel that was open when we triggered global shortcut? (similar to what we can do with message shortcuts)

Answer (score 0):

Interactions in 'GlobalShortcutContext' happen only by 'Modal' windows.

https://api.slack.com/reference/interaction-payloads/shortcuts

Therefore, to send a message back to the user, you need to populate all the details in a 'Modal' window,

 https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals/using#opening_modals

For example :

```
{
    "title": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Response Header"
    },
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "This is a plain text response message.",
                "emoji": true
            }
        }
    ],
    "type": "modal"
}
```

Becomes:

 [image]